# Creating something similar to a pie chart on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, pie-chart

For a project, I have to represent data on something that 'looks' like a pie chart but really isn't. I have to put the data on the circle with 'pie' pieces but in varying circle width and varying transparancy.

Is there something which would let me create such graphics?

EDIT:

It has to be able to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2BjS.jpg

And perhaps even some weather info in the black circle.. 
That's all possible with an object from plot core?

Answer (score 1):

yes of course. you can use coreplot for this pupose. check this:
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/PlotExamples.
It is the best framework to be used for charts in my experience.

Comment: you can divide pie chart into number of portions. but i dont thind one plot can be overlayed over other plot. The image that you are showing contains one pie over other which is not possible

Comment: Not with the core plots but how should I tackle this problem then? I don't have toooo much experience with objective C but I don't mind learning.. I started learning it a couple of days ago (with a broad C/C++ background) and I need to be able to make it for a project

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refer [HUChart](http://github.com/hugo53/HUChart). It is for semi-circle chart, but you can customize the source code for your purpose, or even easier, you can open an issue and request the author support you a chart like your desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's worked for me ,

You can use [dlpiechart](https://github.com/dilipajm/piechart) class of dilipajm in GitHub, then, modify property & var for your purpose. Hope it's useful.